# How to apply 1 Stream to 2 StreamBuilder?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

This is a minimal reproducible code.

```dart
StreamController<DocumentSnapshot> _controller = StreamController.broadcast();
Stream<DocumentSnapshot> myStream = _controller.stream;

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  _controller.addStream(Firestore.instance.document('user/data').snapshots());
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: Page1()));
}

class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Page2())),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: myStream,
          builder: (_, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) return Text('${snapshot.data}');
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: myStream,
          builder: (_, snapshot) {
            print("$snapshot");
            if (snapshot.hasData) return Text('${snapshot.data}');
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When you run this code, 1st `StreamBuilder` displays data, but as you navigate to 2nd page, you'll see my 2nd `StreamBuilder` doesn't show any data, `snapshot.data` returns `null`. Can anyone help?

Edit: I have edited the post and now I am using `StreamController.broadcast()`;

Comment: try https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams#broadcast-streams

Comment: @pskink Sir, I tried them specially `broadcastStream` but it didn't work

Comment: yes it works - i tried that and broadcast stream can be listened multiple times, if it did not work what is the stacktrace you got?

Comment: @pskink broadcast stream does seem to work if you had a regular `Stream`, in above code when I am listening things from `Firestore`, it simply doesn't work, there are no errors,` snapshot.data` returns `null` and `snapshot.connectionState = ConnectionState.waiting`

Comment: so make it "regular stream", cannot you use `StreamController.broadcast()` constructor for example?

Comment: Even that didn't work, there is some problem with `Firebase` snapshots, did you try `Firebase`, is yours working? @pskink

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211477/discussion-between-ikeepchangingname-and-pskink).

Comment: @pskink I added logs.

Comment: and? does `ReplaySubject` work?

Comment: @pskink I didn't quite try it yet, because I started implementing different part of the project, the moment I give it a try in a day or so, I'll surely let you know. Thanks again :)